# Sinon stub error: "Attempted to wrap post which is already wrapped" even though I'm restoring

Tags: javascript, sinon, ava

I have a set of Ava tests using Sinon for stubs. I have several test cases like this one:

```
test('makes a post request', t => {
  const postStub = sinon.stub(request, 'post').resolves({ foo: 'bar' });

  ... some test stuff ...

  request.post.restore(); // for good measure
  postStub.restore();
});
```

With just one such test case, everything works fine. But if I add another test case that stubs `request.post`, I get an error:

```
Attempted to wrap post which is already wrapped
```

I don't know why I'm getting this error, though. After all, I am calling `restore` on the stub. Is there another step I'm missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems with ava asynchronous tests when stubbing with sinon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37900687/problems-with-ava-asynchronous-tests-when-stubbing-with-sinon)

Comment: Yup, you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is because Ava runs the tests concurrently. Running the tests serially fixes the issue.

Comment: This fixes the wrapper issue, but how about the speed, serial tests will slow down the pipeline. It would be good if we can get a fix with parallel flow